# angular-ui-tree drag not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-tree

I'm trying to use [angular-ui-tree](https://github.com/JimLiu/angular-ui-tree) to render a tree.  When I drag the "baz" node, under the "bar" node I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '$$phase' of null`.  Dragging any other node to any other location works fine though.

I don't understand what the error message means.  I'm new to angular.

Here is my code:

http://plnkr.co/edit/G3dHRluoAmjiTmPmBZr2?p=preview

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/JimLiu/angular-ui-tree/master/dist/angular-ui-tree.min.css">

    <style>
      .angular-ui-tree-placeholder {
          background: #f0f9ff;
          border: 2px dashed #bed2db;
      }
      .angular-ui-tree-handle {
          background: #f8faff;
          border: 1px solid #dae2ea;
          color: #7c9eb2;
          padding: 10px 10px;
      }

    </style>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/JimLiu/angular-ui-tree/master/dist/angular-ui-tree.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="treeApp">
    <div class="tree_section" ng-controller="treeCtrl">

      <!-- Nested node template -->

      <script type="text/ng-template" id="nodes_renderer.html">
        <div ui-tree-handle class="tree-node tree-node-content">
          {{id}} {{nodes[id].text}} {{nodes[id].child_ids}}
        </div>
        <ol ui-tree-nodes="" ng-model="nodes[id].child_ids">
          <li ng-repeat="id in nodes[id].child_ids" ui-tree-node ng-include="'nodes_renderer.html'"></li>
        </ol>
      </script>

      <div ui-tree id="tree-root">
        <ol ui-tree-nodes="" ng-model="top_ids">
          <li ng-repeat="id in top_ids" ui-tree-node ng-include="'nodes_renderer.html'"></li>
        </ol>
      </div>

      <p>top_ids: {{top_ids}}</p>

      <script>
      var treeApp = angular.module("treeApp", ['ui.tree']);

      treeApp.controller('treeCtrl', ['$scope',
        function($scope) {

          $scope.nodes = {
            '1': {
              'text': 'foo',
              'child_ids': ['2'],
            },
            '2': {
              'text': 'bar',
              'child_ids': [],
            }
          }
          $scope.top_ids = ['1']

          $scope.nodes['3'] = {
            text:'baz', child_ids:[]
          }
          $scope.nodes['1'].child_ids.push('3');
        }
      ]);

      </script>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution provided by andersManden at github issues seems to be the working solution,

```
   $scope.safeApply = function(fn) {
      var phase = this.$root.$$phase;
      if(phase == '$apply' || phase == '$digest') {
        if(fn && (typeof(fn) === 'function')) {
          fn();
        }
      } else if(phase == null){ 
          fn();
      } else {
        this.$apply(fn);
      }
    };
```

Comment: Link to the comment mentioned:  https://github.com/angular-ui-tree/angular-ui-tree/issues/270#issuecomment-68594119

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to reproduce the error, but I am not able to reproduce,
can you paste the exact error you are getting and when ?

Comment: I created a plunkr, see the link above the code.  Just try to drag the node labeled "baz" under the node labeled "bar" before doing anything else and you can see that it doesn't work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error, and in my case it was because not all of the items in my array had a "children" property. Once I added a children array to every item (even if the children array was empty) the error stopped. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error when having only one parent with a child and dragging the parent a little bit.

The tree was inside a div with an ng-if which removed the tree from the DOM when there were no element.

Using ng-show instead solved my issue.